# Find all instances of a class while debugging in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

I was wondering if the way Java/JVM works means debugging tools like Eclipse can show me a list of all instances of a given class? I suppose one could write some reflection code but I don't want to break execution at the same place every time... rather I;d like to break execution and bring up a list of all `MyClass123` objects in a debug window.

Is this even possible? Is it provided in Eclipse or any plugin?

Comment: You should open the Debug perspective. There is this Variables window that shows the actual variables in the method. Also, you can enable the Expression window to write your own watches and/or execute a method.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it's possible in the standard eclipse debugger. See [here](http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/views/variables/ref-variables_view.htm). While debugging, right-click on a variable entry in the 'Variables View' and then click on 'All Instances':

[image]

This will open a list like this:

[image]

Comment: Hey, can similar thing be done in Intellij Idea too?

Comment: Yes, it's like in eclipse. Right-click on a variable and select `Show [Classname] Objects`

Answer (score 2):

You may want to instatall [**Eclipse Test & Performance Tools Platform**](http://www.eclipse.org/tptp/) plugin in your application and perform `MemoryAnalysis`. This gives you details around all different objects in memory and their references.

You will not need to put any breakpoint in the code. It will gather the required data on its own.

Comment: The "Eclipse Test & Performance Tools Platform" has been archived. Is there a good alternative, that is still supported?