# Where is the "All Instances" debugger option in Kepler?

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

I'm trying to debug some junit tests and noticed some odd behavior. So I wanted to find all instances of a particular class. I did some searching and came across several examples that looked like this: [Find all instances of a class while debugging in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12961671/find-all-instances-of-a-class-while-debugging-in-eclipse)

When I right click, all I see are the following options:

- Select All
- Copy Variables
- Find...
- Change Value... (grayed out)
- New Detailed Formatter...
- Open Declared Type
- Open Declared Type Hierarchy
- Instance Breakpoints...
- Watch
- Inspect

So was this featured removed? Do I need to configure my environment in a certain way to use these features? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. According to this page[1], I have to be using Java 1.6 or better to use these features:

[1] http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Ftips%2Fjdt_tips.html&anchor=debugging_section